Why does this transistor amplifier fail if Rc is greater than 50 ohms?
This simple circuit amplifies a 1 µV 50 ohm 7 MHz signal (e.g. RF off an antenna) quite nicely (31 dB):

However, I'm stumped as to why R2 must be so low (50 ohms), giving a Ic of close to 50 mA.  Raising R2 to 1k still provides 11 mA of Ic, yet ruins all amplification (note the scale is now nanovolts).  Instead, it attenuates:

Why? 11 mA of bias current should be more than enough.  I see, however, that as I raise R2, the voltage at the base goes up, and the voltage at the collector goes down. Along with that, gain goes down, until R2 is about 500R, at which point VCB is about 0.6 V and gain is about 0 dB.  Why?
I conjecture that the cause is along the lines of:

Raising R2 causes less Ic
which lessens Ie
which raises Ve
which lowers Vbe
which lowers Ib
which, multiplied by a factor of beta, lowers Ic
causing the cycle to repeat.

But I am not sure if that is correct, if so how to quantify it, or if so, how it ends.  Furthermore: Why am I seeing the need for such a low Rc on this particular circuit but not in any other standard transistor amplifier.

I've studied the linked questions, and, as Tim requested, am clarifying what's uniquely being asked here:
I understand why we need all 4 resistors: We need R3 and R4 to bias the base.  We need R1 to provide a DC path for bias current.  (We could use a short circuit instead, but this would just waste power while degrading quality.)  And of course the gain comes entirely from having R3.
Likewise, I understand that biasing is important for many reasons and not necessarily best done at halfway between rails.  The question isn't about a particular bias point.
Rather, this is a circuit analysis question: How do I analyze the effect of raising R2? It would seem to me that raising R2 should increase gain.  A small change in Ib results in a larger change in Ic = β * Ib, which results in a change -R2 * Ic in output voltage.  Higher R2 should increase the gain: as long as output voltage (collector) doesn't crash into input voltage (base).
But practically, I'm seeing very different results: We need to keep R2 very low for the circuit to work.  I can't determine the cause, or even determine how to analyze it.  That is this question.

This question is similar to: Biasing in common-emitter amplifier or Why do we need 4 resistors for a common emitter amplifier?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The QP current of BJT is in order of 32 mA (?). If you make R2 higher, the BJT will be saturated ... And the gain should be lowest ...

Max highest R should be ~ 250 Ohm with gain = ~ 30-35 dB (load = 1 k).

@TimWilliams Thanks for the posts. I've studied those and, as explained in the edits, don't see how they answer my question.  (Perhaps the answer is somehow derivable from something there, but that derivation itself is what I'm asking about!)

@Antonio51 Doesn't making R2 greater lower the quiescent current of the transistor? Please see my edits where I explain my analysis as to why I expect raising R2 should increase gain.

Raising R2 should raise also the gain without lowering the current ... But it lowers the Vce of the BJT. So, BJT enters zone saturation region ... which should drastically lower the gain.

This issue is exactly the same as your previous question: Do transistors "prefer" to pull current from their base or collector?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DaveTweed I can believe that the underlying issue is the same, but I'm clearly struggling to understand it.  Perhaps to someone who knows the answer already, the answer is obvious.  But to me - and I believe to others who are learning the field - it's not at all clear, nor is it clear how one question answers the other.  So my question is if you, or any other member of the site, can help me understand how to analyze this circuit, and how to predict correctly the effect of raising Rc.

@SRobertJames I can show an approach pretty quickly, if all you are asking for is how to approach estimating the effects of raising Rc.

I would help you if I thought I could. But to teach someone to build a working transistor amplifier starting from nothing is equivalent to an entire semester of college, and that just doesn't fit in the Q&A format used on this site. It requires everything from Ohm's Law to KCL and KVL, Thevenin and Norton equivalent circuits, to some basic concepts about how a transistor works. You claim to have some knowledge of the basics, but it has become clear from the 65 questions you've asked in the past 12 months that you're dabbling in a wide range of topics with no solid grasp of the fundamentals.

There are plenty of online places to get that kind of background education -- for example, have you checked out OpenCourseWare at MIT? EE.SE is simply not the place for it.

NB: to maintain the BP filter you have at 7 MHz, you should also raise "somewhat" the value of the capacitors ... See the AC Analysis of LTSpice.

Try and keep the conversation to the realm of the question and not focus on people.

I wonder about accurate simulation of RF, using your current understanding of bipolar circuits. But I'll drop that and move on.
A couple of bad things done in that circuit.

Trying to bias the base at \$\frac12 V_{_\text{CC}}\$
Using a very tiny biasing-pair resistor current, as a ratio of the expected collector current.

Those two things stick out like sore thumbs.

For your circuit:

\$V_{_\text{TH}}=V_{_\text{CC}}\cdot\frac{R_4}{R_3 + R_4}\$
\$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac{R_3\,\cdot\, R_4}{R_3 + R_4}\$
\$I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{TH}}}{R_{_\text{TH}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_1}\$
\$I_{_\text{C}}=\beta\cdot I_{_\text{B}}\$
\$I_{_\text{E}}=I_{_\text{C}}+I_{_\text{B}}\$
\$V_{_\text{B}}=V_{_\text{TH}}-I_{_\text{B}}\cdot R_{_\text{TH}}\$
\$V_{_\text{C}}=V_{_\text{CC}}-I_{_\text{C}}\cdot R_2\$
\$V_{_\text{E}}=V_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}\$

Saturation just starts to happen when the collector voltage is the same as the base voltage or else is between the base voltage and the emitter voltage. We can simplify that and just say \$V_{_\text{C}}=V_{_\text{B}}\$ is the moment of initial saturation (to avoid \$\le\$ and \$\ge\$ in the equation.) Until that moment, the bipolar is in active mode. After that moment it is in saturation mode.
So:
vth = vcc*r4/(r3+r4)                # Thevenin voltage of R3 & R4
rth = r3*r4/(r3+r4)                 # Thevenin resistance of R3 & R4
ib = (vth-vbe)/(rth+(beta+1)*r1)    # Use KVL to get this
ic = beta*ib                        # A given, by definition
ie = ic+ib                          # Taking the magnitude
vb = vth-ib*rth                     # Thevenin source, less drop due to base current
vc = vcc-ic*r2                      # Power source, less R2 drop
ve = vb-vbe                         # By definition
R2 = solve(Eq(vc,vb),r2)[0]         # Per condition, Vc = Vb, for saturation
R2
r3*(-beta*r1*vcc - r1*vcc + r4*vbe - r4*vcc)/(beta*(r3*vbe + r4*vbe - r4*vcc))

That allows you to work out the maximum value of \$R_2\$ to avoid saturation (or the minimum value needed to guarantee saturation.) The only assumptions you must apply here are an estimate of \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ and an estimate for \$\beta\$. These will be assumptions. The Spice modeling will do much better at working out those two values. But if you use Spice modeling to capture those two values, then the above equation will yield a value that matches up.
Assuming \$\beta=190\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=750\:\text{mV}\$ (I'm clearly pulling these out of a hat):
R2.subs({r1:50,r3:33e3,r4:33e3,vcc:12,beta:190,vbe:.75})
243.533834586466

So that's the prediction. Here's LTspice:

From those figures, I find \$\beta=179\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=761\:\text{mV}\$:
R2.subs({r1:50,r3:33e3,r4:33e3,vcc:12,beta:179,vbe:.761})
255.329869127227

LTspice provides:

And it appears that now \$\beta=178\$, instead. But it's narrowing down very quickly.
The only remaining question you have is about estimating what happens upon raising \$R_{_\text{C}}\$'s value in your own circuit from \$50\:\Omega\$. That moment you use a word like raising you should immediately think derivative. And you are asking about the sensitivity of the collector voltage to changes in \$R_2\$.
I think you should find a good web page on the topic of sensitivity equations, as I'm not going to teach it here.
But, let's look at what LTspice says:

So \$\beta=192\$ and \$V_{_\text{BE}}=760\:\text{mV}\$. I can now make an estimate of what happens if I make a 10% change:
rho = simplify(derivative(vc,r2)/vc*r2)
(rho*10).subs({r1:50,r2:50,r3:33e3,r4:33e3,vcc:12,beta:192,vbe:.76})
-1.90909918936151

It says that a 10% increase will lower the collector voltage by a magnitude of about 1.91%. Let's test this:

Yup. The sensitivity equation works!

Very helpful! Thank you for the clear and thorough mathematical explanation.

@SRobertJames Thanks for letting me know it helped out! :)

As your model predicts, lowering the bias voltage allows a much higher Rc, and thus much higher gain!  And, in this case, since we're dealing with such a small signal, there's no reason the bias voltage can't be close to ground.  Now, you also write "Using a very tiny biasing-pair resistor current, as a ratio of the expected collector current." Mathematically, I don't see how you concluded this, since even with a low Ib, beta*Ib is still sufficiently large.  And indeed LTspice shows nothing improved by lowering R3 and R4 by a constant factor.

@SRobertJames By "very tiny biasing-pair resistor current" I mean the current from the 12 V supply through those two resistors, which is only 180 uA. Normally, when I see a 50 Ohm resistor at the emitter, I might imagine a collector current of about a volt or two divided by that resistance. On the order of tens of mA. The base current of that will then be about the same magnitude as the earlier 180 uA, about 200 uA? So signal variations of base current are likely to significantly alter the drop across the Thevenin source resistance. Which means the biasing point is no longer true. Etc.

@SRobertJames As a stand-alone circuit that isn't part of something much larger, you should want the drop across the Thevenin resistance to be small with respect to the voltage supply magnitude. A factor of about 100 (scales with $\beta$.) So with 12 V, I'd probably expect to see 120 mV across the Thevenin resistance for biasing purposes. That's not a requirement. But it gets me a ballpark guess of what to expect.

@SRobertJames So, for example, I might guess 1.5 V for Ve, add 0.9 V for Vbe to get 2.4 V for the thevenin base voltage. I'd also set Rth*Ib = Vcc/beta, for example. A solution I get from those two is R3=1912 Ohms and R4=478 Ohms. I'd use R3=1800 and R4=470. For example. Then R2 might be 150 or 180?
